# Não consigo conectar o Jpa com o PostgreSql de jeito nenhum

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Bom estou tentando conectar o **postgresql**, porem, sem sucesso. Minha aplicação será uma aplicação **jsf** e por isso estou utilizando a persistência.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="comunicaVisual"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <jar-file>lib/postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc3.jar</jar-file>
        <class>entys.Pessoa</class>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
        <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testepg" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="336445" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

***O erro que está acontecendo é o seguinte.***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
***Espero que alguem já tenha passado pela situação.***

Answer (score 2):

Um erro genérico de falha na conexão pode ter inúmeras causas. Porém, o ideal é você procurar nos logs da aplicação para ver se há outras pilhas de erro que foram escritas, mas não aparecem na tela. Olhar logs é algo importante, mas muitas vezes ignorado pelos desenvolvedores.

Entretanto, posso listar as causas mais comuns desse tipo de erro:

- Servidor de banco de dados não está iniciado. Você instalou ele, mas não está executando. Talvez o serviço esteja com início manual.
- Servidor não aceita conexões remotas. O PostgreSQL foi instalado em outra máquina e não aceita conexões de outros IPs. Não sou especialista em Postgre, mas este é um problema comum no MySQL.
- Bloqueio na rede. Existe um firewall ou proxy bloqueando a conexão.
- Erro na configuração. Embora eu posso ver sua configuração, o correto é validar usando algum outro programa para ver se nenhum dado foi digitado indevidamente.
- Falta do driver. Por algum motivo a aplicação não está conseguindo encontrar ou carregar o driver do banco de dados. O jar realmente está na aplicação? Será que seu servidor de aplicação consegue carregar o driver de lá? Talvez seja necessário consultar no manual do servidor e talvez instalar o jar como um módulo ou colocar dentro da pasta `lib`.
- Versão incorreta do driver. Já ajudei umas duas pessoas com um problema parecido e a causa era que a versão do driver estar com problemas ou defasada (a instalação do PostgreSQL era mais recente). A solução é pegar o jar mais atualizado possível. Estar com uma versão defasada pode ocorrer com projetos já existentes ou quando alguém copia uma declaração de dependência do Maven de algum site sem consultar o repositório central.

Olhando a configuração postada, vi que é usada a configuração [`jar-file`](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/reference/build/reference/en/html/entityconfig.html) para indicar o jar do Postgre. **Isso está errado!!!**

Não sei se é a causa do erro, mas essa configuração serve para indicar o jar onde estão as entidades JPA. Isso é usado quando o xml de configuração está em um pacote diferente, por exeplo, no caso de aplicações JEE que contém um jar com EJBs.

Portanto, a causa mais provável do erro é a falta do jar no local correto. Lembre-se, o Java encontra *automaticamente* os jars que estão na pasta `WEB-INF\lib` de uma aplicação web, além das pastas de bibliotecas do servidor de aplicação.

Comment: Boa tarde prazer e obrigado pela resposta porem os jars estão adicionados na lib do projeto e no path também agora o erro que está acontecendo é outro [Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('produto_id_seq')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        pessoa
        (nome, id) 
    values
        (?, ?) ] espero que alguém possa ajudar

Comment: @AndreMartins Esse erro aí provavelmente tem alguma coisa a ver com o `SEQUENCE` que vc criou no banco. Você postou parte do log, mas não tem o erro aí. Pode ser um problema no banco, tipo o SEQUENCE não existir ou o usuário usado não ter permissão. Pode ser também erro no mapeamento, como anotação incorreta ou nome do SEQUENCE incorreto. Dê uma verificada e se não conseguir, poste uma outra pergunta colocando sua entidade e detalhes pertinentes sobre a estrutura do banco. Abraço.

Comment: obrigado, o que estava acontecendo era que na tabela no banco tinha um campo a mais... rs porem consegui resolver... estou com outra questão agora é conseguir mudar o esquema na aplicação... no mysql é fácil agora no postgresql está bem complicadinho.

Comment: @AndreMartins Como assim mudar o esquema? Se quiser usar tabelas de diferentes esquemas, apenas use o atributo `schema` na anotação `@Table`.